# Short-circuiting on boolean operands without side effects

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, mingw, compiler-optimization

**For the bounty: *How can this behavior can be disabled on a case-by-case basis without disabling or lowering the optimization level?***

The following conditional expression was compiled on MinGW GCC 3.4.5, where `a` is a of type `signed long`, and `m` is of type `unsigned long`.

```
if (!a && m > 0x002 && m < 0x111)
```

The `CFLAGS` used were `-g -O2`. Here is the corresponding assembly GCC output (dumped with `objdump`)

```
120:    8b 5d d0                mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x30]
123:    85 db                   test   ebx,ebx
125:    0f 94 c0                sete   al
128:    31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
12a:    83 7d d4 02             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c],0x2
12e:    0f 97 c2                seta   dl
131:    85 c2                   test   edx,eax
133:    0f 84 1e 01 00 00       je     257 <_MyFunction+0x227>
139:    81 7d d4 10 01 00 00    cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c],0x110
140:    0f 87 11 01 00 00       ja     257 <_MyFunction+0x227>
```

`120`-`131` can easily be traced as first evaluating `!a`, followed by the evaluation of `m > 0x002`. The first jump conditional does not occur until `133`. By this time, ***two*** expressions have been evaluated, regardless of the outcome of the first expression: `!a`. If `a` was equal to zero, the expression can (and should) be concluded immediately, which is not done here.

How does this relate to the the C standard, which requires Boolean operators to short-circuit as soon as the outcome can be determined?

Comment: Maybe because the compiler knows that comparing PODs is side-effect free? Was this compiled with optimizations on or off?

Comment: I gave the compilation options in my post: `-g -O2`. So yes, with optimizations.

Comment: @RedX: This is C, not C++. "POD" is not defined, and **all** comparisons are side-effect-free (although evaluation of their operands may have side effects, in which case such optimizations would not be possible).

Comment: A comparison is not side-effect free if one of the operands is a function call and the function has side-effects. In such a case, short-circuit might become important. In the code above, it is not.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: R. already covered that: "(although evaluation of their operands may have side effects ...)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this assembly output is a compiler optimization that doesn't affect program execution (as far as the compiler can tell).  If you want to *selectively* disable this optimization, you need to tell the compiler that your variables should not be optimized across the ***sequence points*** in the code.

***Sequence points*** are control expressions (the evaluations in `if`, `switch`, `while`, `do` and all three sections of `for`), logical ORs and ANDs, conditionals (`?:`), commas and the `return` statement.

To prevent compiler optimization across these points, you must declare your variable `volatile`.  In your example, you can specify

```
volatile long a;
unsigned long m;
{...}
if (!a && m > 0x002 && m < 0x111) {...}
```

The reason that this works is that `volatile` is used to instruct the compiler that it *can't* predict the behavior of an equivalent machine with respect to the variable.  Therefore, it must strictly obey the sequence points in your code.

Comment: Cheers! I refrained from improving my answer so somebody who actually needs the rep could get the bounty, and looks like it worked out well. :-)

Answer (score 11):

The C standard only specifies the behavior of an "abstract machine"; it does not specify the generation of assembly. As long as the observable behavior of a program matches that on the abstract machine, the implementation can use whatever physical mechanism it likes for implementing the language constructs. The relevant section in the standard (C99) is 5.1.2.3 Program execution.

Comment: This is informally known as the "as-if" rule - the compiler can generate whatever code it likes, as long as the externally visible behaviour is the same *as if* the written code was executed on the abstract machine.  Accesses to volatile variables are part of the externally visible behaviour, so if you declare `m` as `volatile` then you should see different code generated.

Comment: @caf: You should add that as an answer, I'd +1 it just for the `volatile` comment.

Comment: Depending on the implementation, there might or might not be any possibility of external access to volatile objects. For objects with automatic storage duration whose addresses are never taken, volatile definitely need not have any effects aside from its required interaction with setjmp/longjmp. This may also be the case on implementations where memory is entirely in control of a virtual environment and there is no hardware access or shared memory, especially if the implementation does not have asynchronously-generated signals...

Comment: I don't think it is dependent upon whether there is a possibility of external access (and at least on common platforms, a debugger would give such external access even to automatic storage duration objects).  §5.1.2.3 explicity says that accessing a volatile object is a side-effect, and §6.7.3 says that *"...any expression referring
to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine*".

Comment: There's no requirement that an implementation provide or facilitate a debugger... As far as I can tell, on a purely abstract, isolated implementation where the only inputs and outputs are files, volatile need not impose any restrictions on the compiler except in the presence of setjmp/longjmp...

Comment: I think the restrictions of §6.7.3 would still apply to such an implementation, even if you don't have the ability to prove its noncompliance.  Noncompliance is a matter of objective fact, not subjective experience.  But this is all getting rather philosophical - the OPs platform clearly gives him the ability to determine whether access to volatile objects will be made or not.

Comment: I like this answer the best, but would like the bounty answer to include details (and examples/tests) about methods of bypassing this behavior without lowering the optimization rule. For instance, info on the `volatile` keyword or some similar mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

It is probably a compiler optimization since comparing integral types has no side effects. You could try compiling without optimizations or using a function that has side effects instead of the comparison operator and see if it still does this.

For example, try

```
if (printf("a") || printf("b")) {
    printf("c\n");
}
```

and it should print `ac`

Answer (score 4):

The compiler's optimising - it gets the result into EBX, moves it to AL, part of EAX, does the second check into EDX, then branches based on the comparison of EAX and EDX.  This saves a branch and leaves the code running faster, without making any difference at all in terms of side effects.

If you compile with `-O0` rather than `-O2`, I imagine it will produce more naive assembly that more closely matches your expectations.

Comment: As I've remarked elsewhere, specific memory-mapped devices can and do have a problem with this behavior. So in specific cases, yes, reading memory itself can cause a side-effect.

Comment: In specific cases, yes.  I make no promises for what gcc's doing here, but it's at least theoretically possible they can know the pattern in question is safe.  They already loaded ebp-0x30.  This pulled in not just those four bytes, but a whole cache line.  If ebp is 16-byte or even 8-byte aligned, the cache line included the memory at ebp-0x2c.  In these cases, you have the memory-reading side effect whether you do the comparison or not.  As I say, I don't promise gcc is actually fulfilling all these conditions, but it *could* be.

Answer (score 3):

The code is behaving correctly (i.e., in accordance with the requirements of the language standard) either way.

It appears that you're trying to find a way to generate specific assembly code.  Of two possible assembly code sequences, both of which behave the same way, you find one satisfactory and the other unsatisfactory.

The only really reliable way to guarantee the satisfactory assembly code sequence is to write the assembly code explicitly.  gcc does support inline assembly.

C code specifies behavior.  Assembly code specifies machine code.

But all this raises the question: why does it matter to you?  (I'm not saying it shouldn't, I just don't understand why it should.)

**EDIT:** How exactly are `a` and `m` defined?  If, as you suggest, they're related to memory-mapped devices, then they should be declared `volatile` -- and that might be exactly the solution to your problem.  If they're just ordinary variables, then the compiler can do whatever it likes with them (as long as it doesn't affect the program's visible behavior) *because you didn't ask it not to*.

Comment: Certain types of low-level memory-mapped devices could have issues with this behavior. And it is behavior.

Comment: Are `a` and `m` declared `volatile`?  If so, you should have mentioned it in your original question.  If not, accesses to them are not considered by the language to be "behavior", and the compiler can do anything it likes as long as the visible behavior of the program (input, output, access to volatile objects) meets the language requirements.

Comment: No, they weren't declared `volatile`. And your original answer made no reference of it. :)

Comment: @Unsigned: Definitions of memory-mapped devices which do not define them as `volatile`, though common, are just plain wrong.

Comment: @supercat I fully agree.